# ISBX/apprtc-ios does not work on iOS 13 - no video preview

Tags: ios, iphone, webrtc, apprtc

I am using apprtc-ios from https://github.com/ISBX/apprtc-ios for our video calling project. It is working fine on iOS 12 & iOS 11.

After upgrading to iOS 13,  it seems the front camera does not record video and send it to the other party - If phone A & phone B are having a video calling session, the little video preview square on phone A (iOS 13) turns black. On phone B (iOS 12), there is no video sent by phone A - The whole screen is black, except for the little preview square. The audio conversation is working fine, though.

I checked camera permission - it is on for the app.

And I traced the code. cameraID for the front camera (on iOS 13 phone) is successfully obtained during the video call session.

After several hours of trial and error, I still got no clue. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: No. We are migrating to the latest version of GoogleWebRTC. Hope it'll work.

Comment: Hi. Was the migration to GoogleWebRTC successful? I am stuck in a similar way with AppRTC in iOS13.

Comment: Yes, it works on iOS 13 now!!

Comment: Hii @Fisher, Could you please help me to make it work. I am getting errors after updating dependencies.